# How to change disable state image of nsbutton

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I am new to mac, i am implementing nsbutton, i have two images one in enable mode and other is disable state, I want to change the image based on enable and disable ([button setEnabled:YES]), How can i do that,

Comment: AFAIK the button image should be same irrespective of enable. However you should change the image on button press. So that a good effect is seen.

Answer (score -1):

Use `setImage:` method of `NSButton` class.

```
[button  setImage:anImage];
```